# SQL get data that doesn't exist on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get a query that get me a data that exist in table1 but not on table2, but has the same id with data table2.

In the following example, I'm trying to get 'SecID-by_Bank' 12456 which shares the same ISIN as another 2 items in table2.

I've tried the following query, but it returned me every data that's not on table2, not just the one that shares the same ISIN.

Query:

```
SELECT  tb1_isin, tb1_SecID_by_Bank
 FROM table1
WHERE not EXISTS (
    SELECT top 1 null
    FROM  table2
    WHERE   table1.tb1_ISIN = table2.tb2_isin
)
```

Table 1

```
--------------------------------------------
 Row  | SecID_by_Bank | Desc       | ISIN
--------------------------------------------
1     | 421345        |   BlaBla   | US1354
--------------------------------------------
499   | 34345         |   2.US     | XS1545
--------------------------------------------
500   | 45676         |   2/US     | XS1545
--------------------------------------------
501   | 12456         |   2-US     | XS1545
--------------------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
--------------------------------------------
 Row  | SecID_by_Bank | Desc       | ISIN
--------------------------------------------
1     | 34345         |   2.US     | XS1545
--------------------------------------------
2     | 45676         |   2/US     | XS1545
```

Query result needed:

```
 SecID_by_Bank | Desc       | ISIN
 -------------------------------------
 | 12456       |   2-US     | XS1545
 -------------------------------------
```

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: see below for answer using no subqueries

Answer (score 1):

If you build query in Access try:

`SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.[ISIN]) In (SELECT ISIN FROM Table2)) AND ((Table1.SecID_by_Bank) Not In (SELECT SecID_by_BANK FROM Table2)));`

Or using 1 subquery:

`SELECT Table1.*, Table2.ISIN
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.SecID_by_Bank = Table1.SecID_by_Bank
WHERE (((Table1.ISIN) In (SELECT ISIN FROM Table2)) AND ((Table2.ISIN) Is Null));`

Answer (score 1):

For query in SQLServer:

```
select distinct a.SecID_by_Bank, a.[desc], a.isin from #table1 a left join #table2 b 
on a.SecID_by_Bank=b.SecID_by_Bank and a.isin=b.isin
join #table2 c on a.isin=c.isin
where b.isin is null
```

Comment: Works after removing the # characters.

Comment: yeah thats just for building temp tables in my local environment to test

Comment: Answer updated to use no subqueries for increased performance

Comment: Now I get 'missing operator' error on the edited sql. Missing join type for the ISIN join.

Comment: Works fine for me - did u remove # again?

Comment: maybe you have to use inner join instead of join - try that

Comment: Yes, remove #s. Access does not like that structure at all, regardless of JOIN type used.

Comment: OK yeah im working on sql server so its slightly different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169195/discussion-between-daniel-marcus-and-june7).